# Access index.php of certain directory when there is no trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to know how to get default index.php when there is no trailing slash after folder.

For example -

My website is - `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/abc/xyz`

When I put this url in browser - browser automatically add slash to **xyz/** and takes index.php page under 'xyz' directory but when I use this url with curl then it won't work.

What's the solution for this problem?

P.S. - http://xx.xx.xx.xx/abc/xyz is sample url i am using here but my url structure is same like this

Comment: i think you need to use exact location of file with curl curl did not identify index.php it's for browser to run index file default

Comment: I don't want to use index.php in curl call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found - I created `.htaccess` file with below settings and it works :)

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (?!^.+?/$)^(.+)$ /$1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Just fyi that `DirectorySlash Off` is considered a security risk.

Comment: Test it out with `On`

Answer (score 0):

You need `DirectoryIndex index.php` at top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectorySlash On
```

Comment: It does work unless you have conflicting rule. Keep only these 2 lines in your .htaccess and then try to visit `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/abc`

Comment: it gives me directory listing - all files from that particular directory

Comment: Only if that directory doesn't have index.php you will get listing. If you want to disable that listing it can also be done.

Comment: I have index.php in directory.